# Make importing easier when accessing a namespace within

Tags: typescript, import, export

I have the following file:

```
// FileA.tsx
export default Aaaa {
    export namespace Bbbb.Cccc {
        // Stuff that I want to access
    }
}
```

In another file, I have the following:

```
// FileB.tsx
import Aaaa from "FileA";
import ccc = Aaaa.Bbbb.Cccc;

// ccc.thingINeed
```

I'm looking for a better way to do this.  Having this double line import is very annoying and I end up sometimes doing the double import, and other times directly accessing `Aaaa.Bbbb.Cccc.thingINeed`.

I can't find any details on a way to do this and every attempt I try doesn't work for whatever reason.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution to this.

Make a file that looks like:

```
export import Cccc = Aaaa.Bbbb.Cccc;
```

Then you can consume by doing:

import { Cccc } from "...file/path";

You can also export something as default if you want the original file too.

Answer (score 0):

Use named import

```
export namespace Bbbb {
  // ...
}

import { Bbbb } from './FileA'
Bbbb.thingsYouNeed.
```

Why do you need `Bbbb.Cccc`?

In module system, deep nesting is not encouraged. Ultimately keep things at top-level would be the best.
It allows the consuming code to do tree shaking.